# Android Webview - Video on custom screen area as an overlay for rtsp live video streaming

Tags: android, plugins, webview, android-videoview, rtsp

I have a Webview based Android Application that works with my own application webserver. The application webserver provides HTML5 contents for each user. The content could be rich text, image or any multimedia content.
 In one of my requirement I want to play live rtsp based stream on Android Webview application through a webpage inside a frame, the webpage has other content frames also.

I tried using video tag of HTML5 but it doesn't work for rtsp protocol on Android ICS. I could find many links that suggests to use Android MediaPlayer or Videoview for playing rtsp contents in fullscreen through **onShowCustomView**, however, my requirement is little different.I **don't** want to play video in fullscreen mode.
The video doesn't get started with a href link,it gets started onPageLoad/ready JS event. And I want to play the rtsp streaming video on a particular layout inside the webview as designed by the html5/css logic. My queries are

1. Is it possible to render the videoview/(any control) overlay on top of webview as per the html/css logic to play rtsp stream? If so how?
2. Can it be done on each page load instead of hyperlink?
3. I could write my own rtsp video plugin to play video but I am not sure about integrating my plugin with Webview. There is no enough documentation available for doing so. Is it possible, how?

Thanks
Ash